# Automatic - Generate a pre-configured set of icons from a single source icon

Tags: icons, gatsby, manifest

I have a single icon image with the `favicon.ico` format (I simply renamed it though) inside my `src` folder. I just want to pass the build with no error. Thank you for your help

```
2:34:24 PM: error "gatsby-plugin-manifest" threw an error while running the onPostBootstrap lifecycle:
2:34:24 PM: Input file contains unsupported image format
2:34:24 PM: 
2:34:24 PM: 
2:34:24 PM:   Error: Input file contains unsupported image format
2:34:24 PM: 
2:34:24 PM: not finished onPostBootstrap - 0.026s
```

and this is my gatsby-config.js

```
plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `GatsbyJS`,
        short_name: `GatsbyJS`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#f7f0eb`,
        theme_color: `#a2466c`,
        display: `standalone`,
        icon: `src/favicon.ico`,
      },
    },
  ],
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `.png` image?

Comment: My first attempt was with png. Actually now I `yarn update` and fixed the error at build time (it was on Netlify)

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been finally fixed by upgrading the dependencies with:

```
yarn upgrade
```